# My donut sprinkles transformed in an extremely unusual way, possibly due to geometry nodes problem, can someone help?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry

I had reached part 7 of Blender Guru's latest Donut Tutorial series and I reached a part where... I don't know how to describe this, but here's what happened after some tweaking in the geometry nodes:

[image: I am just as confused as you are, believe me]

[image]

I need help fixing this. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvASN5c_E22hLB9Lh3zaXG1jNzuKsLcE/view?usp=share_link) to my project.

Comment: I think you are supposed to re-watch and re-do tutorials following the instructions more closely if something like this happens. It takes time, but that's how you learn.

Comment: Since this is a beginner tutorial, you should really pay close attention to what he is doing, because you definitely missed some explanations there. First of all, your sprinkles are scaled tiny in _Object Mode_ (and even worse, negative in X and Y axis) and the scale is not reset (Andrew does not show that because he scaled them in _Edit Mode_ and did not need to do it), if you then enable _Reset Children_ they are scaled back to the original size, which is very large. The other thing is, Andrew rotated the sprinkles in _Object Mode_, but then the applied the rotation (and you did not).

Comment: All in all I can only strongly recommend just as @MartynasŽiemys did, to rewatch the tutorial and pay close attention, because we are able to fix it - but mostly by simply re-doing it correctly as shown in the tutorial, which I honestly think is your part in order to learn it, not ours.

Comment: Hi, MELT UP.. To be fair, I think a beginner's tutorial should really press home the difference between an transforming an Object, (in Object Mode) and transforming its geometry (in Edit Mode). In terms.  See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=apply+scale+is%3Aanswer) for how often it trips folks up, especially when scaling. In the light of all those answers, it might be fair to call this a duplicate. (You weren't to know that.) 'Applying' scale  bakes an object's scale into its mesh, and resets the object's scale to 1.